# how to apply vertical-align: middle at div

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I've searched it at online and found some solution. But, nothing works at my project. At most of the solution, I've found:

```
<div class="a">
   <div class="b">
       Unknown stuff to be centered.
   </div>
</div>

.a {
   display: table;
   width: 100%;
}
.b {
   display: table-cell;
   text-align: center;
   vertical-align: middle;
}
```

By applying this technique, I've tried to build something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/L2GZx/1/

The text of left column only needed to be aligned middle vertically. But, it's not working with that technique:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="left">
        <p>Sample Text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <p>Text</p>
        <p>Input Element</p>
        <p>Table</p>
        <p>Image</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="left">
        <p>Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text </p>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <p>Text</p>
        <p>Input Element</p>
        <p>Table</p>
        <p>Image</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="left">
        <p>Sample Text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <p>Text</p>
        <p>Input Element</p>
        <p>Table</p>
        <p>Image</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.row {
    width: 100%;
    background: #ccc;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
    display: table;
}
.left {
    float: left;
    width: 40%;
    padding: 20px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.right {
    float: right;
    background: #fff;
    width: 40%;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

How can I make the text of left-column aligned middle vertically? Note: I can't use any fixed height as content of each row will be different

Comment: remove float from `.left`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.left {
    width: 40%;
    padding: 20px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

removing" float:left " from .left style solves that issue, but using table and div together is not that good.[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/natchkebiailia/L2GZx/6/)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the floats. Floated elements can not also be displayed as table-cells. See [updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L2GZx/2/).

```
.row {
    width: 100%;
    background: #ccc;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
    display: table;
}
.left {
    width: 40%;
    padding: 20px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.right {
    display: table-cell;
    background: #fff;
    width: 40%;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative that I prefer in a situation like this is:

1. To not use display: table-cell, but rather use display:
   inline-block.
2. To then use vertical-align: middle on the element.

Sample (revised) markup / css:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="left">
        <p>Sample Text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <p>Text</p>
        <p>Input Element</p>
        <p>Table</p>
        <p>Image</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.row {
    width: 100%;
    background: #ccc;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
}

.row > div {
    display: inline-block;
    /* below 2 lines are IE7 hack to make inline-block work */
   zoom: 1;
   *display: inline;
   /* below is consolidated css for both left / right divs */
   width: 40%;
   padding: 20px;
}

.left {
    vertical-align: middle; /* or top or bottom */
}

.right {
    background: #fff;
    vertical-align: top; /* or middle or bottom */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is to add a line-height to the left column and it will be automatically aligned (without vertical-align so you can remove it).

Here it is:

```
.left {
    float: left;
    width: 40%;
    padding: 20px;
    display: table-cell;
    line-height:150px;
}
```

And here is your updated **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/KarimAG/L2GZx/18/)**

Answer (score 0):

Using your first example, try something like this. I'll explain how it works in the CSS.

```
<div class="a">
    <div class="b">
        Unknown stuff to be centered.
    </div>
</div>

.a {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative; /* We want our parent div to be the basis of our absolute positioned child div */
    /* You can set your height here to whatever you want */
}
.b {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%; /* Set to be the full width, so that our text is aligned centered */
    text-align: center;
    top: 50%; /* Positions the top of the div at 50% of the parent height */
    left: 0; /* Assures that the child div will be left-most aligned */
    margin-top: -.5em; /* Moves the top of our div up by half of the set font size */
    height: 1em; /* Sets our height to the height of the desired font */
}
```

Here is the JSFiddle link to see a live example: http://jsfiddle.net/L2GZx/20/

This is one of the best solutions to absolutely center text inside of a webpage. It does have it's limitations however seeing how it won't react to other elements inside the same parent and it also has to have a set height. So multiline text will have it's shortcomings with this method.

I hope this helps!